# Sample Pandas based on dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, sample, keyerror

I'm trying to sample a pandas DataFrame based on a dictionary and a specific column. So for each value of `y` column, I know exactly how many observations I would like to pick.

I can do this via a `groupby` `apply` combo as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'y': [2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1], 'x': 1, 'z': 2})

    y   x   z
0   2   1   2
1   2   1   2
2   0   1   2
3   0   1   2
4   0   1   2
5   1   1   2

sizes = {0: 2, 1: 1, 2:1}

df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sizes[x['y'].values[0]]))
```

y       y   x   z

0   2   0   1   2
    4   0   1   2
1   5   1   1   2
2   0   2   1   2

However, if I do `unique` instead of `values` (which should be equivavelent, I get a weird `KeyError: 'y'` error on the dataframe:

```
df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sizes[x.y.unique()[0]]))
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

EDIT:

This happened on `0.23.1` but not on `0.23.1` so this was probably a bug.

Comment: you are grouping by `y` then again taking unique of `y` ? each iteration x has grouped object by `y`.

Comment: Do you think `df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sizes[df.y.unique()[0]]))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `.name` attribute:

```
df1 = df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sizes[x.name]))
print (df1)

     y  x  z
y           
0 4  0  1  2
  2  0  1  2
1 6  1  1  2
2 0  2  1  2
```

If possible some value not match in dictionary use `get` with `0` for not matched values:

```
df1 = df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sizes.get(x.name, 0)))
```

EDIT:

Problem is `unique` return one element numpy array:

```
def f(x):
    print (x['y'].unique())
    print (x['y'].unique()[0])
    print (sizes[x['y'].unique()[0]])
    print (x.sample(sizes[x['y'].unique()[0]]))

df1 = df.groupby('y').apply(f)

[0]
0
2
   y  x  z
2  0  1  2
4  0  1  2
[0]
0
2
   y  x  z
4  0  1  2
2  0  1  2
[1]
1
1
   y  x  z
6  1  1  2
[2]
2
1
   y  x  z
0  2  1  2
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sizes[x.y.unique()[0]]))
print (df1)
     y  x  z
y           
0 4  0  1  2
  2  0  1  2
1 6  1  1  2
2 0  2  1  2
```

Comment: `x.name` is more elegant, didn't know about that. but still why does the other give me an error?

Comment: @niczky12 - added to solution - for debugging is created function `f` same like `lambda func`

Comment: So `df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sizes[x.y.unique()[0]]))` should work, right? Yet I still get the same error. You recon this is a scoping bug in pandas?

Comment: @niczky12 - Yes, for me it working under `pandas 0.23.4`, maybe version dependent problem.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm on `0.23.1`. Thanks for checking!